# Time Complexity Baby Steps Giant Steps

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, cryptography, hash-function, analysis-of-algorithms

This has been driving me mad.  On [wikipedia's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby-step_giant-step) page on baby steps giant steps it gives the time complexity of the algorithm as $O(\sqrt n)$.  It even gives looking up a value in a hash table as how you would implement that in practice.  The thing that's confusing me is my understanding of a hash table means that would only be $O(1)$ for looking at the left coordinate.  Your specifically looking at the right coordinate, which I could see being done in a $O(\log \sqrt n) = O(\log n)$ time which would give a $O(\sqrt n \log n)$ (because you'd have to reapply it $\sqrt n$ times) .  But most everywhere else I'm reading indicates the time for baby-steps giant steps is $O(\sqrt n)$.  What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: The page has "The hashing is done on the second component".  You write "would only be O(1) for looking at the left coordinate.", which suggests you are not thinking of the intended hash table.

Comment: I recall (perhaps incorrectly) that the time estimate $O(\sqrt{n})$ counts group multiplications, which themselves are likely to depend on $n$ as fast as $\log n$, so ignoring factors of $\log n$ is consistent with ignoring the time complexity of multiplication in the group.

Comment: I think your first comment is the meat of the argument.  If you make it so $hash(a^j) = j$ then I think it works.